# Trying to kick people with a specific role, getting no errors but nothing happening either. What do I fix?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Here is my entire code below.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
import asyncio
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Karen has connected to Discord!')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick(ctx, role: discord.Role, reason: str=None):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        if role in member.roles: # does member have the specified role?
            await ctx.guild.kick(member, reason=reason)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

i originally had it as a bot command but kept getting errors, so i tried it as a client instead and now i get no errors, but nothing happening either. the bot is above the role that im trying to kick, and it does have kick permissions. I am currently using discord.py 1.5.1, python 3.9 and pip 20.3.1. I'm confused as to why it does nothing i.e. no errors showing, and no execution of the command that I can see either. I do have someone assigned to that role at the moment.

Comment: Python 3.9 does not have much support for libraries. On the pypi page, 3.9 is not explicitly listed as a compatible version. Try downgrading to 3.8.

Answer (score -2):

Before any more trouble shooting try to check if our bot has administrator powers at all, I had a similar issue. You would have to kick your bot and when authorizing check the "Administrator" check box.

A fix I have seen is to add:

```py
intents = discord.Intents(messages = True, guilds = True, reactions = True, members = True, presences = True)
```

Comment: Bots do not need the administrator role to kick members. It's good practice to only select the permissions that you require.